Why is alembic setting all of my fields as nullable=False?
Here is my model:
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class AppUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = "app_user"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    created_at: Mapped[DateTime] = mapped_column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    updated_at: Mapped[DateTime] = mapped_column(
        DateTime,
        default=func.now(),
        onupdate=func.now(),
    )
    telegram_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BigInteger, unique=True, index=True)
    telegram_username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(60), unique=True, index=True)
    language: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), default="en")
    comment: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))

After I run pdm run alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Create a baseline migrations" I get the following migration script:
def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('app_user',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('created_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('updated_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('telegram_id', sa.BigInteger(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('telegram_username', sa.String(length=60), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('language', sa.String(length=10), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('comment', sa.String(length=255), nullable=False),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_app_user_id'), 'app_user', ['id'], unique=False)
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_app_user_telegram_id'), 'app_user', ['telegram_id'], unique=True)
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_app_user_telegram_username'), 'app_user', ['telegram_username'], unique=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###

Nothing should indicate that telegram_id, telegram_hostname, language, and comment can't be null.  I haven't seen anything in alembic documentation that says this is default behavior and since SQLAlchemy assumes "nullable=True" by default I would assume alembic should as well...

The default behavior of SQLAlchemy (and, therefore, alembic) is not "nullable=True".  It is actually derived from the type annotation (ie Optional or "| None" means nullable):
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapped_column.params.nullable

nullable¶ – Optional bool, whether the column should be “NULL” or “NOT
NULL”. If omitted, the nullability is derived from the type annotation
based on whether or not typing.Optional is present. nullable defaults
to True otherwise for non-primary key columns, and False for primary
key columns.

